# change CSS of child on hover either works in firefox or chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I've made a box which I want to change on hover, I want to change the background color and the color of the text and icon it:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
 <div class="FDCboxHepContainerDIV schmuckBorder">
  <div class="FDCboxHepDIV">
   <i class="fa fa-file-text-o FDCboxHepIcon schmuckFarbe"></i>
   <h3 class="text-uppercase FDCboxHepH3 schmuckFarbe">PRODUCT FOLDER</h3>
   <p class="FDCboxHepp">Download our product folder with more details on ArdenSuite's features and functionalities.</p>
   <a target="_blank" type="button" class="btn btn-borders btn-primary FDCboxHepA">DOWNLOAD</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

looking like this:

[image]

I want the box to change on hover. I want it to have the bordercolor as background and all text and icons in white.
I've figured out a way that works for firefox and one for chrome. but If I add both only firefox works and chrome doesn't.

This is the firefox version:

```html
/*Firefox*/
.FDCboxHepContainerDIV:hover .FDCboxHepIcon{
 color:white !important; 
}
```

This is the Chrome version:

```html
/*Chrome*/
.FDCboxHepContainerDIV:hover > .FDCboxHepIcon{
 color:white !important; 
}
```

Does anyone know a way for this to work in both, preferably all browsers. Also the CSS for this box is spread around different css files overwriting each other.

Comment: Are you trying to change the background of the box or just the button?

Comment: The second definition shouldn't work because `.FDCboxHepIcon` is not an *immediate* child of `.FDCboxHepContainerDIV`. See [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors). That being said, it's hard to tell what's going on without a working example. Though I imagine the problem has something to do with "css files overwriting each other".

Comment: @GurmeharSingh i want the background of the whole box and the color of the text the icon and the button to white

Comment: @showdev surprisingly it works in chrome but that's a good point i'll try following the strick parent child line.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. Apparently Chrome had some issues with a background-color being rgba without the opacity value. as soon as I took the "a" away it worked. I currently have a tight sceduel but I might go back to this and experiment some more.